# Existence of an $\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality

Let $V(x)=x_1^2x_2^2 $ be a polynomial defined on  $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, we denote
$A_V(x)=\sum\limits_{2\le |\alpha|\le 4}|\partial^{\alpha}_xV(x)|^{\frac{1}{|\alpha|}}$.

Please help me to find an  $0<\epsilon<\frac{3}{4}$ 
such that the following result is true:

There exists a constant $c>0$ such that 
for all $x,x_0\in \mathbb{R}^2$ 
$$|x-x_0|\le \frac{1}{\Big(A_V(x)\Big)^{\frac{1}{4}+\epsilon}}\, \text{ implies }\,\left(\frac{\Big(A_V(x)\Big)^{\frac{1}{4}+\epsilon}}{\Big(A_V(x_0)\Big)^{\frac{1}{4}+\epsilon}}\right)^{\pm 1}\le c$$

Comment: $A_V(x)=\sum\limits_{2\le |\alpha|\le 4}|\partial^{\alpha}_xV(x)|^{\frac{1}{|\alpha|}}=|2x_2^2|^{\frac{1}{2}}+|4x_1x_2|^{\frac{1}{2}}+|2x_1^2|^{\frac{1}{2}}+|4x_2|^{\frac{1}{3}}+|4x_1|^{\frac{1}{3}}+|4|^{\frac{1}{4}}+|4|^{\frac{1}{4}}$

Comment: By the way, for "implies", write **\Rightarrow** or **\rightarrow** or **\Longrightarrow** to generate $\Rightarrow$, $\rightarrow$ and $\Longrightarrow$ respectively.

Comment: What is $\partial^\alpha_x$ for negative $\alpha$ ???

Comment: we have $\alpha\in \mathbb{N}^2$